Do linear functionals map the zero vector to the zero in the field?
Let $X$ be a linear space (vector space, Euclidean space, etc.). Let $X'$ be its dual space, i.e. the set of linear functions $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ or $(\mathbb{C})$. If $f$ is any linear functional for $X$, then is it true that $f$ maps the zero vector of $X$, call it $0_X$, to the zero of the field $0_F$ (in our case $0 \in \mathbb{C}$)?
I'm thinking yes because $f(0_X) = f(v-v) = f(v)-f(v) = 0_F$. Similarly, if $f(0_X) = c \neq 0$, then $f(0)= f(v-v) = f(v)-f(v)=c \implies f(v) = f(v)+c$ which is a contradiction

This is true for all linear mappings (not necessarily continuous etc).

Your proof is correct. Another way to think about this is to note that the field is a vector space over itself (with basis $1$), that a linear map between vector spaces must be a homomorphism of the underlying additive group structures, and that group homomorphisms always map identities to identities. A fancier way to state this would be by replacing the word "group" with "module", but the argument remains the same.
